# What were the terms of the covenant of brotherhood between Israel and Tyre?

Tags: israel, covenant, amos, kings, exile

Reference to 1 Kings 5:12. Since nations had no relations of blood, by virtue of a treaty, they had a relationship of brotherhood. Hence, Tyre and Israel were brothers.
Reference to Amos 1:6, Tyre exiled a whole nation of Israel to Edom, this means this was one of the terms they weren't supposed to break. Are there others?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

The "treaty" בְּרִית (berith) = "Covenant", or agreement of 1 Kings 12:5 between King Solomon and King Hiram is actually spelled out (not necessarily fully) in **1 Kings 12**.  The preamble and purpose of the Covenant/Treaty is in 1 Kings 12:3-5

What King Hiram of Tyre agreed to do:

- Cut cedar logs, V6
- Haul the logs to the sea, V9
- Float them on rafts down to an Israelite port, V9
- Sort and separate the logs ready for transport to Jerusalem and other places, V9
- Allow Solomon's men to work alongside Hiram's men, V6

What King Solomon agreed to do:

- Pay the wages of all the Sidoniam workers, V6
- Supply food for the Hiram's household, V9
- Pay 20,000 cors of wheat, V10
- Pay 20,000 cors of pure olive oil, V10
- Supply about 10,000 mean to help with all this effort, V14

According to 1 Kings 9:28, there was also an agreement to sail trading ships with Tyre/Sidon as well.  See also 2 Chron 8:17, 18, 9:21.

There is a parallel passage in **2 Chron 2** which gives a more complete picture of the treaty between Solomon and Hiram.  After a preamble and statement of purpose in V3-6, we have -

What King Hiram of Tyre agreed to do:

- Supply skilled craftsmen to work on the temple in Jerusalem, V7
- Supply cedar, cypress, algum logs
- Allow Israelite men to work with Sidonian workers

What King Solomon agreed to do:

- Pay 20,000 cors of ground wheat, V10
- Pay 20,000 cors of barley, V10
- Pay 20,000 cars of wine, V10
- Pay 29,000 cors of pure olive oil, V10
- Supply workers to help with the huge task to work with the Sidonians, V17, 18

As to the record in Amos 1 -

- V6 concerned Gaza which was 207 km south of Tyre
- However, V9 concerns the prophecy of rebuke and doom for Tyre because it did not remember its treaty with Jerusalem.  On this Ellicott suggests:

> (9) The brotherly covenant.—The “covenant of brethren” (margin) was
> the league made between Hiram and David, and afterwards between Hiram
> and Solomon (2Samuel 5:11; 1Kings 5:1; 1Kings 5:12). This ancient
> covenant was forgotten in Phœnicia’s mercantile cupidity, and Tyre was
> tempted to sell Hebrew captives to Greeks and Idumeans. (Comp. Isaiah
> 23; Ezekiel 26)

Barnes has a similar comment -

> "This brotherly covenant Tyre remembered not," when they delivered up
> to Edom "a complete captivity," all the Jews who came into their
> hands. It seems then, that that covenant had an special provision
> against selling them away from their own land. This same provision
> other people made for love of their country or their homes; the Jews,
> for love of their religion. This covenant Tyre remembered not, but
> brake. They knew doubtless why Edom sought to possess the Israelites;
> but the covetousness of Tyre fed the cruelty of Edom, and God punished
> the broken appeal to Himself.